# How to get the range of the first line in a string?

Tags: swift, string, range, nsrange

I would like to change the formatting of the first line of text in an `NSTextView` (give it a different font size and weight to make it look like a headline). Therefore, I need the range of the first line. One way to go is this:

```
guard let firstLineString = textView.string.components(separatedBy: .newlines).first else {
    return
}
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: firstLineString.count)
```

However, I might be working with quite long texts so it appears to be inefficient to first split the *entire* string into line components when all I need is the first line component. Thus, it seems to make sense to use the `firstIndex(where:)` method:

```
let firstNewLineIndex = textView.string.firstIndex { character -> Bool in
    return CharacterSet.newlines.contains(character)
}
// Then: Create an NSRange from 0 up to firstNewLineIndex.
```

This doesn't work and I get an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '`(Unicode.Scalar) -> Bool`' to expected argument type '`Character`'

because the `contains` method accepts not a `Character` but a `Unicode.Scalar` as a parameter (which doesn't really make sense to me because then it should be called a `UnicodeScalarSet` and not a `CharacterSet`, but nevermind...).

My question is:

#### How can I implement this in an efficient way, without first slicing the whole string?

(It doesn't necessarily have to use the `firstIndex(where:)` method, but appears to be the way to go.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String.Index` range for the first line in `string` can be obtained with

```
let range = string.lineRange(for: ..<string.startIndex)
```

If you need that as an `NSRange` then

```
let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: string)
```

does the trick.

Comment: or simply `"".startIndex..<"".endIndex`

Comment: @LeoDabus: That might work by chance, but collection indices are only meant  to be used with their “own” collection. Using `"".startIndex` as index into a different string is (I think) undefined behavior.

Comment: you are correct. better to use the standard approach

Comment: @LeoDabus: Or with partial ranges: `..<string.startIndex`  and `string.endIndex...`

Comment: Sleek, short, works. I always find it a little "unnatural" to first create some arbitrary range of which we know that it's in the first line. It's not very expressive because there are many possible choices for that range. However, the simplicity of these two line make up for that in my opinion.

Comment: Wow, I just understood the immense consequences of working with non-integer indices that only have a meaning with respect to their own collection: If you want to compare two strings by iterating over them character by character, for example, you cannot just use a single index for both strings and increment it in every loop (like `firstString[i] == secondString[i]`) – you have to maintain two different indices and increment both of them with `index(after:)`! That's crazy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rangeOfCharacter`, which returns the `Range<String.Index>` of the first character from a set in your string:

```
extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {
    var partialRangeOfFirstLine: PartialRangeUpTo<String.Index> {
        return ..<(rangeOfCharacter(from: .newlines)?.lowerBound ?? endIndex)
    }
    var rangeOfFirstLine: Range<Index> {
        return startIndex..<partialRangeOfFirstLine.upperBound
    }
    var firstLine: SubSequence {
        return self[partialRangeOfFirstLine]
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
var str = """
    some string 
    with new lines
"""
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
let firstLine = NSAttributedString(string: String(str.firstLine))
// change firstLine as you wish

let range = NSRange(str.rangeOfFirstLine, in: str)
attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: firstLine)
```

Comment: `rangeOfCharacter` is definitely the best approach to find the first newLine index in a String. Btw since Swift 4 you should create a generic method on `StringProtocol` instead of `String` to allow the use of this method on substrings as well

Comment: `CharacterSet` is redundant

Comment: On your first property one liner `return ..<(rangeOfCharacter(from: .newlines)?.lowerBound ?? endIndex)`. On your second property you need to change the return type to `SubSequence`. No need to initialize a new `String` object

Comment: @LeoDabus, I'll add your improvements to the answer, if you don't mind :)

Comment: I don't. I was gonna post it anyway.

Comment: Looks good. The only thing is that I end up with a `PartialRangeUpTo<String.Index>` rather than an `NSRange` which is required when I want to change the first line's attributes using [`replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with attrString: NSAttributedString)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1417045-replacecharacters). Is it possible to convert this?

Comment: @Mischa you can easily create your range using the original string startIndex and  partial range upperBound

Comment: `extension StringProtocol where Index == String.Index {
        var firstLineRange: Range<String.Index> {
            return startIndex..<(rangeOfCharacter(from: .newlines)?.lowerBound ?? endIndex)
        }

        var firstLine: SubSequence {
            return  self[firstLineRange]
        }
    }`

Comment: @Mischa, added usage example

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these ideas! Learned a lot from that. It definitely works and what I like about it is that it's relatively expressive as your going with a range `..<(rangeOfCharacter(from: .newlines)`. This makes it clear to the programmer that you're going from position zero up to the first line break. However, I personally prefer Martin R's solution as it's a lot shorter and feels like this is the way the function is supposed to be used.